# Table and text over footer

Tags: tables, sectioning, tabularx, text, footer

When i try to put a table on the code below, text or the table gets over footer. And the text below that code does not appear on the next page.

Does anyone knows how to correct it?

```
 Text before table.....blablabla........This text gets over the footer or 
 sometimes is the table that gets over the footer... either way, once it 
 gets over the footer the rest of the table or text does not go to the next 
 page

\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption{Table name.}
    \label{tab:}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X  X  X }
       \toprule
        Info & Info & Info \\
        \midrule
        Info & Info & Info \\
        Info & Info & Info \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\subsection{Title}
\label{sec:}

Tex, blablablablablabla - This text just disappears.....
```

Comment: I recommend using float option `t` or `b` instead of `h`. However, if you want to keep the table in that place, then have a look at `longtable`.

Comment: @JouleV i have tried to change the float options, however it does not solve the problem. Independently on the position of the table, the text get over footer and de next subsection does not appear.

Comment: @MarianaMoreira: Please make a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the issue.